# Binary search with mid index equals to $\frac{(right + left )}{2}$

Tags: algorithms, binary-search

I have tried to implement traditional binary search on an array. Now, if I set the mid index to be $mid = \frac{(right + left )}{2}$, my code does not run within time quota specified already, however, If I run it with $mid = left + \frac{(right - left )}{2}$ it works fine. Can you please give a hint what might be the source of problem given that both versions of $mid$ are indeed equal to each other?

Both $left$ and $right$ are set to first index and last index of array respectively.

```
public boolean isPerfectSquare(int num) {
    long left = 0, right = num;
    while (left <= right) {
        long mid = left + (right - left) / 2, t = mid * mid;
        if (t == num) return true;
        else if (t < num) left = mid + 1;
        else right = mid - 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This does not work and exceed time limit on leetcode:

```
public boolean isPerfectSquare(int num) {
    long left = 0, right = num;
    while (left <= right) {
        long mid = (right + left) / 2, t = mid * mid;
        if (t == num) return true;
        else if (t < num) left = mid + 1;
        else right = mid - 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: overflow error? [wiki: implementation issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Implementation_issues). "Although the basic idea of binary search is comparatively straightforward, the details can be surprisingly tricky" — Donald Knuth

Comment: @HendrikJan. I thought $mid$ versions above should be equivalent since both yield same result.

Comment: @Avv, are you able to find the size of the array on which your code run out of time limit?

Comment: @JohnL. Yes. The point is mid above are equivalent, so not sure why $left +\frac{right-left}{2}$ works while the other don't?

Comment: @Avv. Please tell us what is that size for which your code run out of time limit. Can you post the relevant part of the code? Basically, I am asking for [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a clear description of the problem.

Comment: @JohnL. This is based on leetcode execution engine. So, not sure how to bring that here. I still don't see how $mid$ version makes difference here anyway.

Comment: Depending on the language and on the implementation details, the two expressions might not be equivalent. For example consider C++ and let `int M = std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`. Then $M+(M - (M-1))/2$ is a well-defined expression that is equal to $M$, while the expression $(M+(M-1))/2$ results in undefined behavior (the same problem occurs for any value of $M$ that is greater than `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()/2+1`).

Comment: @JohnL.. Just did that. Thank you.

Comment: (Independant of the problem of *computing* mid,) You don't need `long` if you work with `factor = num / mid`.

Comment: How does *checking for perfect square* relate to `tried to implement traditional binary search on an array`?

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Implementation_issues): "this can result in an arithmetic overflow for very large arrays. If the midpoint of the span is calculated as $\frac {L+R}{2}$, then the value of $L+R$ may exceed the range of integers of the data type used to store the midpoint, even if $L$ and $R$ are within the range. [...] this can be avoided by calculating the midpoint as $L+{\frac {R-L}{2}}$"

Comment: @Avv I submitted both Java snippets in the question to [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-perfect-square/). Both passes with 0ms. I am wondering whether you and I are on the same planet.

Comment: @JohnL. Thank you. I don't know why that happened with me though! That is why I was confused. I will try it out again and let you know.

Comment: (@HendrikJan: If your en.wikipedia quote was to be addressed to me: binary search yes, but where's any *array*?)

Comment: @greybeard It was a quote making explicit my first comment above. The question here mentions "binary search on an array", hence my explanation from wiki. It was not meant specially for you. Indeed, where did the array go?